# Unable to add event into DataTable Pagination buttons when using setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I'm working on a Table that logs all action and refreshes the table based on the interval given.
Everything works fine except when using `setInterval`, here's my code:

```
  var interval = 3000;
  var interval_en = true;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#logs_tbl').DataTable();
    $('.paginate_button,.paginate_button.current').click(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("paginate click");
        interval_en = false;
    }).change(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("paginate click");
        interval_en = false;
    });
    var aclogs_interval = setInterval(function () {
        if(interval_en){
            console.log("logging=true");
            aclog_refresh(); //This function refreshes the table via Ajax
        }else{
            console.log("logging stopped");
            clearInterval(aclogs_interval);
        }
    }, interval);
} );
```

What have I tried so far:

Different selector:

> ```
> $('#logs_tbl_paginate a').click(function(){
>    interval_en = false;
>    clearInterval(aclogs_interval);
> });
> ```

Binding per interval:

> ```
>    var aclogs_interval = setInterval(function (e) {
>         if(interval_en){
>             console.log("logging=true");
>             aclog_refresh();
>             $('.paginate_button,.paginate_button.current').click(function(){
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 console.log("paginate click");
>                 interval_en = false;
>             }).change(function(e){
>                 e.preventDefault();
>                 console.log("paginate click");
>                 interval_en = false;
>             });
>         }else{
>             console.log("logging stopped");
>             clearInterval(aclogs_interval);
>         }
>     }, interval);
> ```

Though manually triggering `interval_en = false;` in the browser console will stop it. Still can't find out what went wrong.

Also clicking the pagination buttons before the first interval occur works.

Comment: your first code snippet does not work as `e` is undefined. assuming that was just a copy/paste error, I think the code should work. I would look into the datatable library itself and see if there's a better way to "hook" into their events as any solution with a polling interval is inferior to an event based approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
    $('#logs_tbl').on( 'page.dt', function () {
        console.log("paginate click");
        $('.btn-live,.btn-notlive').prop('class','btn-notlive');
        interval_en = false;
    } );
```

This example is reference by [datatable](https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) site.

Comment: thanks for this, didn't know that `page.dt`, should have ready the documentation properly.